# If $f(z)$ is an entire function, prove that it has a zero at $z_0$ of order $k\ge 1$ iff $z_0$ is a simple pole of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function. Prove that $f(z)$ has a zero at $z_0$ of order $k\ge 1$ iff  $z_0$ is a simple pole of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ and the residue of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ at $z_0$ is $k$.
Ok, so I know that every entire function $f(z)$ can be represented as a power series $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ where $n\gt1$ that converges everywhere in the complex plane. So I can say that $f(z)$ is differentiable everywhere. So, would I just be able to take the polynomial function maybe and work with that, $f(x) = a_nx^n + a_{n−1}x^{n−1} + . . . + a_2x^2 + a_1x + a_0$?

Continuing from @Raclette's answer below,

$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{k}{(z-z_0)g(z)} + \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$or $=\frac{k+g'(z)(z-z_0)}{(z-z_0)g(z)}$

Comment: how is "zero of order k" defined in your lecture?

Comment: It should probably be "of order $k > 0$" (or $k\geqslant 1$). Write $f(z) = (z-z_0)^m\cdot g(z)$ with $g$ holomorphic and $g(z_0) \neq 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, corrections were made. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(z) = (z-z_0)^k g(z)$ where $k$ is the order of the zero of $f$ at $z_0$ (i.e., if $k=0$ then $f$ has no zero at $z_0$ and if $k < 0$ then $f$ has a pole at $z_0$) and $g(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Then $f'(z) = k(z-z_0)^{k-1}g(z) + (z-z_0)^kg'(z)$.

Now, what is $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$?

Comment: give me a minute,I'm not as fast. Will put up my proposed solution shortly.

Comment: does the above seem correct to you?

Comment: yes! Here, the first term has a pole of order 1 unless $k=0$. The second term is analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$, as $g(z)$ is.