# >$f(z)$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0 \iff F(z)=f'(z)/f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z_0$. Find the residue of $F$ at $z_0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f(z)$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0 \iff F(z)=f'(z)/f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z_0$. Find the residue of $F$ at $z_0$.

[This Questions suggests that the residue is n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057955/if-fz-is-an-entire-function-prove-that-it-has-a-zero-at-z-0-of-order-k-g)

However, could somebody help me complex my calculation? *Edit: I figured that the person made an error in their calculation, however, can the question be solved using my method?* The answer $n$ can be obtained using simple differentiation

Let $f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$, then since $f(z_0)=0$ I can rewrite:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac {f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}=f'(z)$$

Then using residue calculus:

$Res(F,z_0)=(z-z_0)f'(z)/f(z)=f'(z)/f'(z)=1$ , which is valid for $n=1$/

Now do I need to use induction?

Answer (score 4):

Write $f(z)=(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ with $g(z_0)\ne0$. Then
$$
F(z)=\frac{n(z-z_0)^{n-1}g(z)+(z-z_0)^ng'(z)}{(z-z_0)^ng(z)}
=\frac{n}{z-z_0}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}
$$
and $g'/g$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $z_0$ since $g(z_0)\ne0$. So, by inspection of the former identity, $z_0$ is a pole of order $1$ with residue $n$.

Comment: A nice shortcut is to use [logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation), since that's what the question is about.